# Can you provide no knowledge SaaS, if server only serves requests with a VPN/Tor IP address?

Tags: vpn, identity, tor, anonymize, anonymity

to protect users you would reject serving requests originating from non-VPN/Tor IP addresses.

how can you get and keep updated a list of

1. the Top/most secure VPN providers's IP addresses? (others won't be approved by/work with the service)
2. Tor exit nodes IP addresses?

Answer (score 2):

Tor exit nodes can be listed with https://check.torproject.org/cgi-bin/TorBulkExitList.py, or you can get them programmatically like a DNS lookup using https://www.torproject.org/projects/tordnsel.html.en

The problems with listing VPN IP addresses are many:

- There are many VPN providers, and they change frequently;
- Some VPN providers provide reasonable security, many do not, and it's
  extremely difficult to verify;
- Users can roll their own VPN using a cloud service;
- Many VPNs do NOT want their IP addresses known, and may even change
  them regularly, in order to increase protection for their users.

Comment: VPNs don't assure anonymity, only encryption in between the endpoints of the VPN and a different IP address than your entry point machine. Traffic is still subject to sniffing by the VPN provider or after the exit point of the VPN.

Comment: I've not thought once about it just as casually since the hour it was down voted, since I was learning/researching if SaaS can be no/0 knowledge with crypto-payments, 
now I know better, that w/o client-side encryption, No; which SaaS can't go with, so thinking about IP anonymity was pointless.

anyways, seems that Netflix succeeded in blocking Most VPN providers in the past year, according to top VPNs reviews & comparisons articles on the web.
It'd be interesting the read an article/paper with their findings about the challenges and how they solved them, if they will/can ever publish any.